# Touch screen panel using LVDS interface

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32f7

Hi i am thinking to connect a 14 inch or bigger lcd touch screen with my discovery boards. Currently i have stm32f4 and stm32f7 discovery boards.
Currently i am aware of different methods to connect them. But i am most interested in LTDC. I have tried using old protocols like Motorola 6800  Parralel RGB. But Touch screens of bigger size and bigger resolution available on Alibaba for example does not support them.

Please correct me in my understanding if i am wrong that for bigger screen size and bigger resolution old protocols like Motorola 6800 , Intel® 8080 bus and SPI protocol wont work. Because bigger touch screens found in market does not have them.

Will Parallel RGB connection be able to work with bigger screen. If yes can u give me a link for that.

The devices i see are coming with lvds connection. Will they be able to work with stm32 discovery kits. If yes than how.

Finally can u suggest me some good working tutorials for them apart of datasheet.

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RGB can be used to drive larger display panels. However, you will need to convert the signal to LVDS.

Assuming you are using the STM32756G-EVAL you could link the LCD modules connector (CN20) to J1 and J2 (depending whether your display panel is single or dual LVDS) of Texas Instruments’ LDI demo kit Transmitter board http://www.ti.com/general/docs/litabsmultiplefilelist.tsp?literatureNumber=snlu036a